# Slack bolt npm package gives Error: Cannot write headers after they are sent to the client

Tags: node.js, runtime-error, slack-api, slack-bolt

After calling bolt.client.views.update(), the bolt packages returns `Error: Cannot write headers after they are sent to the client` which is intermittent. The update() method seems to be successful though.

The @slack/bolt package version is 3.12.2.

What does the error mean?
Could this error be related to node version upgrade from 18.17.1 to 20.10.0 ?